# How to pass parameters from one page to a report viewer in another page

Tags: asp.net, .net, report, reportviewer

I am trying to generate a report by passing parameters selected using two drop down menus which are in `page1.aspx` and sending them to `page2.aspx` which is the page for my report viewer (and the report i want to generate).

I tried to use the `response.redirect` command and `server.transfer` command with the help of `click_button` event from my code behind page for `page1.aspx` but it didn't work.

Can any body help me how to do this, i am trying to figure this out since a really long time and i am new to ASP.NET, i also tried to google it but couldn't find any information regarding the same. Any help would be really appreciated. Thank you

I repeat the question:

**What is the way to transfer parameters from page1.aspx to a report viewer in page2.aspx** such that the parameters are selected using two dropdown menus in page1.aspx and are used as a criteria to generate report in page2.aspx?

Answer (score 0):

You could create an object class where you save the state of parameters.

Inside that object you create 2 variables par1 and par2.

In page1.aspx when you define what the parameters are, assuming this is not directly a report parameter, but still has to be passed into a report that you will load, you could create a new instance of the class object, store the variables within, and reference that object in page2.aspx when calling the report url into the reportviewer.

In case you are loading parameters inside the report, i think you need a dataset in report1 that uses a stored procedure that includes saving the parameters in a database table. That way, in your second report you can call for this stored data directly in the database.

Those 2 solutions i think should do. If you need more help let me know.